# Can I run a script not from "main"

Tags: python

EDIT: Use question #2 since "main.py" is not a standard, just a naming convention for Pycharm. Changing the scriptpath is what to do.

I've been reading Python Crash Course and I'm confused as to how they are running a file that is not "main.py" as the executable. I don't know what is the best practice for this specific question so I've done 3 things:

1 - "from alien_invasion import alien_script" within the "main.py" file and then run the code specifically from "alien_script"

```
if __name__ == "alien_invasion.alien_script":
run_game()
```

2 - change the main scriptpath of Pycharm

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\unit tests\main.py" 
into  
"C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\unit tests\alien_invasion\alien_script.py
```

3. Ignore all of this and just import the code from the module and run it inside main

If anyone has documentation to help I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The script being called `main.py`, and `__name__ == "__main__"` have nothing to do with each other. `__name__ == "__main__"` happens when you call any script via `python foo.py`, and indicates that you ran the file directly rather than, say, importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are asking for adding multiple classes inside one script, you would do this:

```
class ClassName:
    variable = "test"

classTest = ClassName()
print(classTest.variable) --> "test"
```

Comment: I'm not asking for either of these answers but thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to know? I might be able to help. Is there an example code you have?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I realized I can just change the scriptpath in Pycharm to the specific file. I was thinking "main.py" was a standard for python developers to use but Pycharm just makes a file for you and you can just change it to whatever. Process of learning I guess.